# sum of an array using angular for each

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

```
function dialogController(generate, $scope) {
$scope.profiles = generate.get_keys('::role');
$scope.content = {};
$scope.options = [];
$scope.servers = {};
$scope.subs = {};
$scope.discountList = {};
$scope.total = {};

$scope.toggle = function(item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
        list.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
        list.push(item);
    }
};
$scope.contentList = function(name) {
    $scope.content = generate.get_config('::role::' + name).items;
    // console.log($scope.content);
};

$scope.priceMapping = function(subscriptionPrice) {
    var obj = {
        'bronze': [129, 0.5],
        'silver': [165, 0.5],
        'gold': [199, 1],
        'platinum': [265, 1]
    };

    return obj[subscriptionPrice];

};




$scope.calculatePrice = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.options, function(opt) {
        $scope.discountList[opt] = {};
        $scope.discountList[opt].servers = $scope.servers[opt];
        $scope.discountList[opt].subscription = $scope.subs[opt];

        var price = (Math.pow($scope.servers[opt], 0.75)) * $scope.priceMapping($scope.subs[opt])[0];
        console.log(price);
        var hours = Math.round((($scope.priceMapping($scope.subs[opt])[1]) * (Math.pow($scope.servers[opt], 0.75))) * 10) / 10;
        console.log(hours);


        $scope.discountList[opt].price = price;
        $scope.discountList[opt].hours = hours;

    });

    var totalPrice = 0;
    var totalHour = 0;


};
```

}

Here I want to calculate total price and total hours using angular for each. Prices and hours are present in discountList{}.

How could I calculate total price and total hours?

discountList{} contains price and hours so how could I  calculate the total of them?

Comment: So, can you show us some example data in `discountList`?

Comment: discountList: ::role::web::java
:
Object
hours
:
4.8
price
:
1260.5595419028843
servers
:
8
subscription
:
"platinum"::role::web::perl
:
Object
hours
:
3.3
price
:
665.3966034515399
servers
:
5
subscription
:
"gold"

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in controller which will calculate it for you.

```
<div>Total: {{ getTotalHours() }}</div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.getTotalHours= function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.discountList.length; i++){
        var item = $scope.discountList[i];
        total += item.hours;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems ambiguous, but this is probably you need.
Initially, set `totalPrice` and `totalHours` to 0, in `angular.forEach` iterate thru each object and add it to the variable.

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function() {
    $scope.totalPrice = 0;
    $scope.totalHour = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.options, function(opt) {
        $scope.discountList[opt] = {};
        $scope.discountList[opt].servers = $scope.servers[opt];
        $scope.discountList[opt].subscription = $scope.subs[opt];

        var price = (Math.pow($scope.servers[opt], 0.75)) * $scope.priceMapping($scope.subs[opt])[0];
        var hours = Math.round((($scope.priceMapping($scope.subs[opt])[1]) * (Math.pow($scope.servers[opt], 0.75))) * 10) / 10;

        $scope.discountList[opt].price = price;
        $scope.discountList[opt].hours = hours;

        $scope.totalPrice += price;
        $scope.totalHour += hours
    });
    console.log("Total Price : ", $scope.totalPrice);
    console.log("Total Hours : ", $scope.totalHour);
};
```

HTML

```
<div> Total Price : {{totalPrice}}</div>
<div> Total Hours : {{totalHour}}</div>
```

Comment: how to show total price in html ?like: <div>Total price:</div>

Comment: Use `$scope` to bind variables and interpolate its value in html. See the update to answer.

Comment: <div flex="20"  style="margin: 0 0 0 5px">
                        {{(discountList[data.fqpp])?discountList[data.fqpp].price + ' Euro':'-'}}
</div> here i am showing only price but i want show the price after two decimal (e.g- price= 452.33445566..i want price = 452.33) how to do this in angular here only ?